# How to replace login screen system

Tags: 20.04, login, crash, login-screen, 21.10

I'm having issues with my the default ubuntu login system, because

- It takes FOREVER to load when I close and open my laptop
- It often doesn't load correctly, the dock icons are missing and opening the applications menu makes ubuntu unusable, so i gotta kill my pc with the power button
- Sometimes I enter the password, it loads for a long time, screen goes black, and then i'm back at the login screen
- Sometimes it just refuses to load after I close and open my laptop, it only shows a black screen
  I'm not interested in changing the theme or the background image, I wanna change the entire mechanism behind the login screen because it's been nothing but a pain ever since I installed ubuntu. (these issues happen with me in 20 LTS, 21.04 and 21.10)
  Reinstalling doesn't help either. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried a different desktop environment? Different flavours of Ubuntu use different greeters and flavours like Lubuntu and Xubuntu are much lighter than others.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al /var/crash` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. What EXACT make/model laptop? Which CPU? What video card and driver version? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 doesn't have a login/greeter (20 != 20.04 and 20 is intended application is headless so it makes no sense); for 21.04 & 21.10 desktop systems that's `gdm3` by default - which is easily replaced; but that likely won't change much - just the way the login look to me (ie. I don't believe it's your issue; as `gdm3` is a cut down GNOME using services GNOME requires running on login, so using another won't help login time; just change the way the login looks/works)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)